# How to integrate Android app and website?

Tags: android, web

I have no idea how does applications like Amazon,  Flipkart etc work.  They have both android application and website.  How does data between both web and Android synchronise?

1. Do we write separate codes for building android app and website? If yes then in what language we build the website so that it's compatible with the android application.
   And how to build the database for the same.
2. If answer is no to the above question,  then how exactly do we proceed to build such Android and web application.

I am new to this and want to learn how to build it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, web sites are built with web technologies such as JavaScript, HTML, and CSS, but there a many different frameworks and libraries in other languages (such as Angular, which is written in TypeScript) that can also handle the creation of web apps. In comparison, mobile applications for Android and iOS are written it Java/Kotlin or C#/Swift, respectively. There isn't really a clean, native way to create a single app for web and mobile platforms. But, the data that backs both of the platforms is the same.

How does this work? The data is hosted on what is called a backend, a server that has the information that you want to display to your users. Typically, the client app can get this information with an HTTP request to the backend, and the response will be the data formatted in a JSON string. Data is stored in the backend in a database. There are many databases in use today, but some more popular ones are MySQL, MongoDB, and SQLite, and each of them have their advantages and disadvantages. As you get further along in your development cycle, you will need to choose the tools that work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Websites (and relative applications) like Amazon have very complicated systems behind what you see on the screen. Of course they have different code for either application and website. Usually, in small projects, you can create the mobile android app with languages like Java or Kotlin and websites with html, css and Javascript. But when it comes to get together data between an app and a website, you will need to write backend software, which is not so easy, for example in php and then create a database to store the data (with mySQL for example). Then you can access your data from either app and website and decide what to do with it. I suggest you to learn one of these technologies at a time. Trying to learn them all together will only create misunderstandings.
Hope I've been useful.